# unrecognized selector sent to instance, but I can't figure out why

Tags: objective-c, ios

This is an error that my friend is getting when testing my app, but I can't reproduce it. I'll start with code:

TransferFrequency.h

```
@interface TransferFrequency : NSObject
- (BOOL)isImmediate;
// Other details...
@end
```

TransferFrequency.m

```
@implementation TransferFrequency
// Other details...
- (BOOL)isImmediate
{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Transfer.h

```
@interface Transfer : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) TransferFrequency* frequency;
// Other details...
@end
```

Transfer.m

```
@implementation Transfer
@synthesize frequency;
// Other details...
@end
```

CreateTransferView.h

```
@interface CreateTransferView : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) Transfer* transfer;
// Other details...
@end
```

CreateTransferView.m

```
@implementation CreateTransferView
@synthesize transfer;

// Other details...

- (void)confirmButtonTouched
{
    // The crash happens on the following line, as confirmed by stack trace
    if([self.transfer.frequency isImmediate])
        // Do some stuff
}
@end
```

When the user touches the confirm button, `confirmButtonTouched` is called. This is the error my friend is getting:

```
-[TransferFrequency isImmediate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xeec6db0
```

It appears to me that the selector `isImmediate` is being called on a legitimate `TransferFrequency` object, but the iPhone is saying it can't find that selector.

There are actually several iPhones that are reporting this error to me but I do not have physical access to any of them, so I'm stuck debugging from afar. My own iPod touch, iPhone, and iPhone Emulator all work just fine.

Any ideas as to what may be causing this?

Comment: Did you create frequency object in Transfer init method, or if this object got TransferFrequency from any other object? (this same question to CreateTransferView.transfer)?

Comment: The code looks good, the only issue I could imagine that would lead to the effect that you are describing is a corruption of the dispatch table stored in the `isa` pointer of your `TransferFrequency` object.

Comment: @TomaszWojtkowiak: CreateTransferView creates a new Transfer object in `viewDidLoad` using `[self setTransfer:[[Transfer alloc] init]]`. The TransferFrequency object is set when a user chooses one. `self.transfer.frequency = someFrequencyObject`

Comment: This may sound stupid, but what are the CPU architectures of the devices exhibiting the problem and of the devices which work?

Comment: @Costique: I'm reaching out to the owners of the iPhones exhibiting the problem to get this information for you.

Comment: Make sure that `self.transfer.frequency != nil` before you call `isImmediate`, I have strong hunch, that bug is here.

Comment: @TomaszWojtkowiak: `self.transfer.frequency` is in fact not nil. However, if it were nil, I would not be getting an 'unrecognized selector' error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sorry to waste everybody's time. My friend is distributing the app for testing from his own machine. It turns out that he needed to clean and rebuild the project. Works great now.

Anyway, thanks for the help, everyone. And the lesson here is that if you're having a problem that doesn't really make sense, clean and rebuild!

Answer (score 2):

First, if you're running the debugger with breakpoints, can you confirm that self.transfer is actually assigned and represents an instance of a Transfer at the time confirmButtonTouch is called?

My thoughts:

1)You're naming a class starting with 'Create'. Create carries a convention with method names, so I try to avoid using it in general (unless I specifically want to conform to the convention).

2)You might try isolating your ivar names be explicitly assigning them:
@synthesize *aTransfer = __aTransfer;

My motivation here would be that somewhere/how classes are being mixed up with instances are being mixed up with properties... You have a several similar names being tossed around, I would seek to isolate everything as much as possible given that I don't see any other problems jumping out... you might have some name collisions.

Comment: I'm aware of the naming convention with 'Create' and I have confirmed that using the proper capitalization with the class name does not cause a problem. And I understand your motivation for changing ivar names, but could that be the problem when the problem happens on some phones but not others?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but I also wouldn't think there is a problem with this code simply to look at it.